# Keep an object in CQ5 session for all users

Tags: java, session, aem

I need to read and fetch values from an XML file kept in the DAM. The file is 111 MB in size and takes forever to unmarshall and then equally long time to find the value I am looking for.

I am using JaxB to unmarshall the XML file and then iterating through the list. But most of the times I face timeouts and heapspace error while parsing it.

Is there any way to keep the unmarshalled object in the session and fetch it from there whenever a user needs to search some data in it ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this file change regularly or is it static and just placed in DAM for convenience? What I suggest here is to have a OSGi service that reads and parses the file on activate and keeps the relevant data in a format that suits your search needs best.

Comment: @Thomas .. This file changes regularly and we will have a scheduled service to fetch, unzip and replace the file in DAM before activating it. Do you suggest it is possible to write an OSGi service that unmarshalls it on activation and keeps the POJO object for further use ?

Comment: In this case your service needs to implement the javax.jcr.observation.EventListener which checks for modification of this specific file. Then the service can unmarshall it and store the extracted data in a service property. Depending on your needs, a Map where the key is your search value is probably the fastest to retrieve data. If it is more complex, you could also just transfer the XML file into JCR Nodes where you have the full query language at your disposal.

Comment: Observation EventListener approach is low level and likely cause of performance issues see if you can take other high level approaches. Check http://techagyan.blogspot.in/2015/02/aem-event-handling-and-filtering.html if it helps.